# Calculus used in Statistics

Tags: calculus, statistics

**Formula**:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\log(\pi/2)-x+\log(1+x^2))=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}-1$$

I have calculated the derivative as above. Then I set the derivative $=0$, for my understanding, the original equation is maximised when $x=1$, because $x^2-2x+1=0$. However, from what I observe, the original equation is maximised when $x=0$. Which part of my understanding goes wrong? Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any image.  Anyway, it would be better to learn how to enter formulae rather than just post images.

Comment: @badjohn done~~

Comment: Do you mean maximised over the interval $x\geq0$? Since if $x<0$ were allowed, the function would be unbounded.

Comment: It is possible for a (continuous differentiable) function to reach its maximum or minimum at the extreme of its range without having a zero derivative there

Comment: @WantToLearnNewSkills Your original picture of the equation had $\log(\pi*2)$ and now it is $\log(\pi/2)$. Irrelevant to the question, but still :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculate the derivative to be zero at $x=1$, which is correct, but if you plot this function you'll see this isn't a maximum or a minimum - its an inflection point. Moreover, this function has its largest value (in the range $x\geq0$) at $x=0$, but it doesn't have zero derivative there, since that's where the function stops. What you can take away from this is, for functions which are defined on an interval, you should check the value of the function at the interval endpoints, since the extrema could be at these points, where derivative doesn't have to be $0$ for it to be a max/min.

Answer (score 0):

When finding a maximum of a function, $f(x)$ , consider all points where the derivative is 0 **and** the function's endpoints. The original function is defined everywhere except $x=0$ so consider the following points:

1. When the derivative is 0.
   $$f(x)=\log(\pi/2)-x+\log(1+x^2)$$
   $$f'(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}-1=0 \implies x=1$$
   $$f(1)\approx1.837877$$
2. The limit to $-\infty$
   $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=\infty$$
3. The limit to $\infty$ 
   $$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=-\infty$$
4. The limit to $0^-$ 
   $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=-\infty$$
5. The limit to $0^+$ 
   $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=-\infty$$

Therefore the function is maximized at $x=-\infty$, and has a **local** maximum at $x\approx1.837877$